instruction #5 didn't work
I'm trying to minify NFT and ran into the fact that my instruction #5 didn't work.
1- This is the transaction where I mined manually: Transaction Hash
2ihkj3LqAbDwQUe2GWDGQT2YxWhHsMevuLoBWp1pxYoZi9BwLVgwd721jLRq6rN7uG8AvcE2Gu19UpimiEZr3J3Q

And here I mined with the code, and it was in this transaction that there was a problem with the fifth instruction: Transaction Hash
2H3eY2D65aN3wdZyooUUyc2u2WYs5FS8bFynQnrhsmhPbYAUUTVqV1Awcp6A5H91TSwQcA99nJ1gofkB6r9r3cEJ

Bottom line, I want to understand why the transactions failed and my instruction didn't work, even though everything went well in the first transaction.

Please send more information such as which network you are on? Testnet, Devnet, Mainnet etc.
Also recommend you copy paste the Transaction / Instructions

Recommend you paste your Transaction into the Solana Inspector
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/inspector
That might help
